# Setting a elements background to transparent makes it white

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to set the color for a header on a wordpress website to transparent, so that the logo and menu icon show over the website's other elements and do not have their own background.

My issue is the following. The CSS that sets the header color is the following, in my **app.css** file:

```
header.dark-header {
background-color:#252627;
border-color:transparent;
border-bottom:0;
}
```

If I set that to transparent, the background actually turns white and is not transparent.

Images explaining the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3GNm.jpg
Website demo: http://security4.forebet.ro

I have no idea what to do or why this is happening. Anybody?

Comment: This means it's parent element has a white background.

Comment: That was probably it. It was taking the bg color of the body, which was white. Anyways I solved the problem by modifying the theme's app.css file with the correct properties from another class that was toggled by [data-transparent-header="false"], when set to true it was looking right so I just copied that CSS over the main one. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting `background-color: transparent;` should do the trick.

So like this:

```
header.dark-header {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`transparent` is the default value for `background-color`, so if the element's background turns white when you use it, the default is probably being overridden by a parent element where `background-color` has an explicitly set value. Short of digging through your stylesheet and changing this (probably the best solution), you can use the CSS rgba() function to explicitly set the header's background opacity to zero like this:

```
header.dark-header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom:0;
}
```

Although be advised that browser support for the rgba() function is still [a little spotty](https://caniuse.com/#search=rgba).